# cannot get parameter value from button element

Tags: reactjs

I am working on my a reactjs application with firebase,i have completed all but i am stuck with one problem,i have an edit todo option where i can edit my todo in database,for that i need an id and which i got from the defined button,but now i also need a previous todo before editing and put it in place of input text,so the people can see whats the previous and what i wanna change,i have defined it in button also but i cannot the value in function,i have logged both id and todo text but i only get id where as in place of todo i get undefined in console can someone help me please

Function

```
const editModalHanlder = (e) => {
    setIsEditModelOpen(true);
    const id = e.target.id;
    const todo=e.target.todo
    console.log(todo)
    console.log(id)
    setEditId(id);
  };
```

Button

```
<button
    id={todo.id}
    todo={todo.todo}
    onClick={editModalHanlder}
    className="button"
    >
```

Comment: This is not the right approach. Please have a look on react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: i still cannot figure out can you please be precise

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get the id and `todo` from `event`. So why don't you pass that info you need instead of depending event, like:

```
<button
    id={todo.id}
    todo={todo.todo}
    onClick={() => editModalHanlder(todo.id, todo.todo)}
    className="button"
    >

const editModalHanlder = (id, todo) => {
    setIsEditModelOpen(true);
    console.log(todo)
    console.log(id)
    setEditId(id);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button
    id={todo.id}
    value={todo.todo}
    onClick={editModalHanlder}
    name="button"
    className="button"
    >

const editModalHanlder = e => {
   console.log(e.target.name);
   console.log(e.target.value);
  };
```